# Converting integers to English words

Tags: code-golf

The goal of this code golf is to convert integers to English words.

The program prompts for input. If this input isn't an integer, print `NaN`. If it is an integer, convert it to English words and print these words. Minimum input: 0 (zero). Maximum input: 9000 (nine thousand).
So, `5` returns `five` (case doesn't matter), and `500` returns `five hundred` or `five-hundred` (dashes don't matter).

Some other rules:

A `one` before `hundred` or `thousand` is optional: `one hundred` is correct, but `hundred` too (if the input is `100` of course).

The word `and` in for example `one hundred and forty five` is optional too.

Whitespace matters. So, for `500`, `five-hundred` or `five hundred` is correct, but `fivehundred` is not.

Good luck!

Comment: There is an ungolfed answer here http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0426.html .

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3911982/1237747) answer in SO does similar stuff but isn't code-golf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Perl 281 bytes

```
print+0eq($_=<>)?Zero:"@{[((@0=($z,One,Two,Three,Four,Five,@2=(Six,Seven),
Eight,Nine,Ten,Eleven,Twelve,map$_.teen,Thir,Four,@1=(Fif,@2,Eigh,Nine)))
[$_/1e3],Thousand)x($_>999),($0[($_%=1e3)/100],Hundred)x($_>99),
($_%=100)>19?((Twen,Thir,For,@1)[$_/10-2].ty,$0[$_%10]):$0[$_]]}"||NaN
```

Newlines added for horizontal sanity. The above may be used interactively, or by piping it a value via stdin.

Works correctly for all integer values on the range *[0, 19999]*, values outside this range exhibit undefined behavior. Non-integer values will be truncated towards zero, and as such, only values which are truly non-numeric will report `NaN`.

Sample usage:

```
for $n (14, 42, 762, 2000, 6012, 19791, 1e9, foobar, 17.2, -3) {
  print "$n: ", `echo $n | perl spoken-numbers.pl`, $/;
}
```

Sample output:

```
14: Fourteen
42: Forty Two
762: Seven Hundred Sixty Two
2000: Two Thousand 
6012: Six Thousand Twelve
19791: Nineteen Thousand Seven Hundred Ninety One
1000000000: Thousand 
foobar: NaN
17.2: Seventeen
-3: Nine Hundred Ninety Seven
```

Comment: "1000000000: Thousand "? And shouldn't 17.2 print "NaN"?

Comment: @DavidCarraher _"... values outside this range exhibit **undefined behavior**. Non-integer values will be truncated towards zero, and as such, only values which are truly non-numeric will report `NaN`."_

Comment: I'm not a Perl expert, so I ask this question: does this program prompt for input?

Comment: @ProgramFOX I have updated it to read a value from stdin (if run interactively, it will prompt the user for a value), instead of as a function.

Answer (score 14):

### JavaScript (375)

Probably a terrible attempt, but anyway, here goes...

```js
alert(function N(s,z){return O="zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thir,,fif,,,eigh,,,,twen,,for".split(","),(z?O[s]||O[s-10]||O[s-20]:s<13?N(s,1):s<20?N(s,1)+"teen":s<100?N(a=20+(s/10|0),1)+"ty"+(s%10?" "+N(s%10):""):s<1e3?N(s/100|0)+" hundred"+(s%100?" "+N(s%100):""):s<1e5?N(s/1e3|0)+" thousand"+(s%1e3?" "+N(s%1e3):""):0)||NaN}(prompt()))
```

Pretty-printed (as a function):

```js
function N(s,z) {
  return O = "zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thir,,fif,,,eigh,,,,twen,,for".split(","),
      (z? O[s] || O[s-10] || O[s-20]
       : s < 13?  N(s,1)
       : s < 20?  N(s,1) + "teen"
       : s < 100? N(a=20+(s/10|0),1) + "ty" + (s%10?" "+N(s%10):"")
       : s < 1e3?  N(s/100|0) +  " hundred" + (s%100?" "+N(s%100):"")
       : s < 1e5?  N(s/1e3|0) + " thousand" + (s%1e3?" "+N(s%1e3):"") : 0) || NaN
}
```

Sample conversion (note that it even outputs `NaN` when out of bounds, i.e. invalid input):

```
540: five hundred forty
4711: four thousand seven hundred eleven
7382: seven thousand three hundred eighty two
1992: one thousand nine hundred ninety two
hutenosa: NaN
1000000000: NaN
-3: NaN
```

Comment: `+1` its quite difficult to do better in a language like javascript. (you can remove the space in `N(s,z) {return` to save 1 char)

Comment: Oh, haha, must've missed that one. I also seem to have missed a bunch of chars in the `O` string. I'll fix that..

Answer (score 11):

## Mathematica <s>60</s> 57

```
f = ToString@#~WolframAlpha~{{"NumberName", 1}, "Plaintext"} &
```

**Usage:**

```
f[500]
```

> five hundred

**Edit:**

```
InputString[]~WolframAlpha~{{"NumberName", 1}, "Plaintext"}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. I said that the user has to input a number (using the command line, or a prompt box for example), and then your program should output the words (on the command line, or in a message box for example). Your code is just a function to convert it, and your program doesn't ask for input.

Comment: @ProgramFOX it says 'The user inputs something'.  That does not mean 'The program prompts for input'.

Comment: @MrZander: Well, 'The program prompts for input' was actually what I meant. I update my question, but of course, it would be unfair if I wouldn't upvote alephalpha's answer, so he got my +1

Answer (score 9):

## Lisp, <strike>72</strike> 56 characters

I realize 1) that this is old, and 2) that it relies entirely on the standard library to function, but the fact that you can get the c-lisp printing system to do this kind of thing has always impressed me.  Also, this does in fact take the input from a user, convert it, and print it.

```lisp
(format t "~:[NaN~;~:*~r~]" (parse-integer (read-line) :junk-allowed t))
```

It totals 72 characters.

- `:junk-allowed` causes parse-integer to return nil on failure instead of raising an error.
- `~:[if-nil~;if-non-nill]` conditional predicated on nil, handles NaN where necessary
- `~:*` backs up the argument interpretation to re-consume the input
- `~r` prints the number as an english word string, as requested, except with full corrected punctuation

Sample:

```
17823658
seventeen million, eight hundred and twenty-three thousand, six hundred and fifty-eight

192hqfwoelkqhwef9812ho1289hg18hoif3h1o98g3hgq
NaN
```

Lisp info mainly from [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_parse-integer.html).

### Edit, golfed properly down to 56 characters

```lisp
(format t "~:[NaN~;~:*~r~]"(ignore-errors(floor(read))))
```

This version works rather differently. Instead of reading a line and converting it, it invokes the lisp reader to interpret the input as a lisp s-expression, attempts to use it as a number, and if any errors are produced ignores them producing nil to feed the format string conditional.  This may be the first instance I've seen of lisp producing a truly terse program... Fun!

- `(read)` Invokes the lisp reader/parser to read one expression from standard input and convert it into an appropriate object
- `(floor)` attempts to convert any numeric type into the nearest lower integer, non-numeric types cause it to raise an error
- `(ignore-errors ...)` does what it says on the tin, it catches and ignores any errors in the enclosed expression, returning nil to feed the NaN branch of the format string

Comment: It's certainly no problem that the question old :) I edited your answer to include the language name and the character count in a header.

Comment: Thank you for the edits, I haven't gotten the Stack* syntax for these things down yet.  Went back in and fixed a mistake I made in the description of the conditional in the format string as well.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>327</s> <s>310</s> 308 bytes

```
<?$a=['',one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thir,0,fif,0,0,eigh];echo($n=$argv[1])>999?$a[$n/1000].' thousand ':'',$n%1000>99?$a[$n/100%10].' hundred ':'',$n?($k=$n%100)<20?($a[$k]?:$a[$k%10]).[teen][$k<13]:[2=>twen,thir,'for',fif,six,seven,eigh,nine][$k/10].'ty '.$a[$k%10]:zero;
```

takes the number as parameter, works for 0<=n<=12999

**breakdown**

```
// define names
$a=['',one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,
    ten,eleven,twelve,thir,0,fif,0,0,eigh];
// print ...
echo
    ($n=$argv[1])>999?$a[$n/1000].' thousand ':'',                  // thousands
    $n%1000>99?$a[$n/100%10].' hundred ':'',                        // hundreds
    $n?
        // if remains <20:
        ($k=$n%100)<20?
            ($a[$k]?:$a[$k%10]) // no value at index (0,14,16,17,19)? value from index%10
            .[teen][$k<13]      // append "teen" for $k>12
        // else:
        :[2=>twen,thir,'for',fif,six,seven,eigh,nine][$k/10].'ty '  // tens
        .$a[$k%10]                                                  // ones
    // "zero" for $n==0
    :zero
;
```

Answer (score 2):

## SAS, 70 characters

```
data;window w n;display w;if n=. then put 'NaN';else put n words.;run;
```

The `window` and `display` statements open up the SAS command prompt. Input for `n` goes on line 1. This takes advantage of the SAS format `words.` which will print the number as a word or series of words with "and", " ", and "-" as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

**PHP**

777 characters

This is definitely a terrible attempt, but you can't accuse me of taking advantage of any loopholes, plus it's a very lucky number. Thanks to ProgramFOX for the tip.

```
<?php $i=9212;$b = array('zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine');$t='teen';$c = array('ten','eleven','tweleve','thir'.$t,$b[4].$t,'fif'.$t,$b[6].$t,$b[7].$t,$b[8].$t,$b[9].$t);$d = array('','','twenty','thirty','fourty','fifty','sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety');$e='hundred';$f='thousand';$j=str_split($i);if (strlen($i)===1){$a=$b[$i];}elseif (strlen($i)===3){$k=1;$a=$b[$j[0]].' '.$e.' '.x($j,$k);}elseif (strlen($i)===4){$k=2;$a=$b[$j[0]].' '.$f.' '.$b[$j[1]].' '.$e.' '.x($j,$k);}elseif (substr($i, -2, 1)==='1'){$a=$c[$j[1]];}else{$a=$d[$j[0]].' '.$b[$j[1]];}$a = str_replace('zero hundred','',$a);echo $a;function x($j,$k){global $i, $b, $c, $d;if (substr($i, -2, 1)==='1'){return $c[$j[$k+1]];}else{return $d[$j[$k]].' '.$b[$j[$k+1]];}}
```

**Long hand**

```
<?php
// Input
$i=9212;
// 0-9
$b = array('zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine');
// 10-19 (Very tricky)
$t='teen';
$c = array('ten','eleven','tweleve','thir'.$t,$b[4].$t,'fif'.$t,$b[6].$t,$b[7].$t,$b[8].$t,$b[9].$t); 
// Left digit of 20-99
$d = array('','','twenty','thirty','fourty','fifty','sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety');
// Hundreds
$e='hundred';
// Thousands
$f='thousand';
// Split input
$j=str_split($i);
// 1 digit inputs
if (strlen($i)===1){$a=$b[$i];}
// 3 digit input
elseif (strlen($i)===3){$k=1;$a=$b[$j[0]].' '.$e.' '.x($j,$k);}
// 4 digit input
elseif (strlen($i)===4){$k=2;$a=$b[$j[0]].' '.$f.' '.$b[$j[1]].' '.$e.' '.x($j,$k);}
// 10-19
elseif (substr($i, -2, 1)==='1'){$a=$c[$j[1]];}
// 20-99
else{$a=$d[$j[0]].' '.$b[$j[1]];}
// Fix for thousand numbers
$a = str_replace('zero hundred','',$a);
// Result
echo $a;
// Abstracted function last 2 digits for 3 and 4 digit numbers
function x($j,$k){
    global $i, $b, $c, $d;
    // 10-19
    if (substr($i, -2, 1)==='1'){return $c[$j[$k+1]];}
    // 20-99
    else{return $d[$j[$k]].' '.$b[$j[$k+1]];}
}
```

Comment: I think you can shorten your code by creating arrays like this: `array('zero','one','two')`.

Comment: @ProgramFOX or even `['zero','one','two']` (php 5.4+). And if you don't mind `E_NOTICE`, `[zero,one,two]` would work as well.

Comment: I should update it, but 777 is such a lucky number.

Comment: +1 for your efforts. PHP is tragically underrepresented in code golf.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2.x - 378

Derivative of Fireflys answer, although by changing `P` to include million or trillions, etc..  it could recursively be used for any range of positive numbers. This also supports values up to 999,999

```
O=",one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thir,,fif,,,eigh,,,,twen,thir,for,fif,,,eigh,".split(",")
P=",thousand".split(',')
def N(s,p=0):
 h,s=divmod(s,1000);x=N(h,p+1)if h>0 else" "
 if s<20:x+=O[s]or O[s-10]+["","teen"][s>12]
 elif s<100:x+=(O[s/10+20]or O[s/10])+"ty"+N(s%10)
 else:x+=N(s/100)+"hundred"+N(s%100)
 return x+" "+P[p]
print N(input())
```

Sample test (input is `<<<`, output is `>>>`):

```
<<< 1234
>>> one thousand two hundred thirty four

<<< 999999
>>>  nine hundred ninety nine   thousand nine hundred ninety nine
```

Although, if someone can explain this odd "buffer underflow" issue I have, that'd be swell...

```
<<< -1
>>>  nine hundred ninety nine

<<< -2
>>>  nine hundred ninety eight
```

Comment: `print divmod(-2,1000) #-> (-1, 998)`

Comment: Oh of course. I was thinking it might take an absolute value or something. But there is `-1*1000` and a "remainder" of `998`.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, <s>365</s> Three Hundred Forty Seven bytes

```
DIM N$[22]D$="OneTwoThreeFourFiveSixSevenEightNineTenElevenTwelveThirFourFifSixSevenEighNineTwenFor
WHILE LEN(D$)INC I,D$[0]<"_
INC N$[I],SHIFT(D$)WEND
INPUT N
W=N MOD 100C%=N/100MOD 10M%=N/1E3T=W<20X=W/10>>0?(N$[M%]+" Thousand ")*!!M%+(N$[C%]+" Hundred ")*!!C%+(N$[X+10+(X==2)*8+(X==4)*7]+"ty "+N$[N MOD 10])*!T+N$[W*T]+"teen"*(T&&W>12)+"Zero"*!N
```

There's a trailing space if the last one or two digits are 0.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 11 bytes

```
⌈≠[`NaN`|∆ċ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLijIjiiaBbYE5hTmB84oiGxIsiLCIiLCJ0b3AgdGVuIGJydWggbW9tZW50cyJd)

Easy win when it's a built-in :p

Comment: @Lynn now it does

Comment: If you use 2.16.x or something `kn` works?

Answer (score 0):

## [MOO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOO_(programming_language)) - <s>55</s> 83 bytes

```
x=$code_utils:toint(read(p=player));p:tell(x==E_TYPE?"NaN"|$string_utils:english_number(x))
```

Note: this code does not print any prompt to the standard output.

As a bonus, this code can handle any number withing the bounds of the moo language (`2147483647`-`-2147483648`).

Answer (score 0):

## Wolfram Language <s>27</s> 40 bytes

Making use of the native function, `IntegerName`,

```
 Check[Input[]~IntegerName~"Words","NaN"]
```

The above prompts for user input.  The present implementation returns "NaN" if the user enters anything other than an integer.

---

**Some examples (with pre-set inputs)**:

```
 Check[243~IntegerName~"Words","NaN"]
```

> two hundred forty-three

---

```
 Check[1234567890~IntegerName~"Words","NaN"]
```

> one billion, two hundred thirty-four million, five hundred
>   sixty-seven thousand, eight hundred ninety

---

```
 Check["abc"~IntegerName~"Words","NaN"]
```

> NaN

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 333 bytes

```python
def f(n):S=str.split;D=S('z one two three four five six seven eight nine');K=' fif six seven eigh nine';k=n/1000;n,m=n/100%10,n%100;e,d=m/10,m%10;return' '.join([k and f(k),'thousand']*(k>0)+[D[n],'hundred']*(n>0)+([S('ten eleven twelve thir four'+K)[d]+'teen'*(d>2)]if 9<m<20else[S('twen thir for'+K)[e-2]+'ty']*(e>0)+[D[d]]*(d>0)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY8/b4MwEMX3fgovlXGgqQ39AyVkypYxI2Ko5KO4wIGMCU2/PDXQCtTF8rt37@537c0UDfrjKCEnuYPs7ZJ0Ru@7tlImPiUXh36TBoGYoSGm0AAkb3pNcnUF0qkv0sEVkID6KAxBhUBZfE6o9fN/9uLGZYKPgnMeo1cv33vBPbQPj8GTSW1LXm1lrMH0Gimh@89GoZOW5B2lZSyZRy1031lJs51THjlz01OKmUeLHqWGuYxT2UntAWYiqGYQM0BlwU2h9HwHdc8slZlrewDpzpFHn2UWPTrUB59D1cE8YJiiS2aJwIM/hW7TIvjdL7NsGsAZY2OrFRrLKsKA3f2JZ/GyiqfgdRW@CEXkbzqjjbd@Q7ERgdg2RSEbfwA)

This is good for 1 to 999,999, inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, <s>239</s> 242 bytes

```
L:rjdb6"  +"dAm+cd;"nine"," one two three four five six seven eight""  twen thir for fif six seven eigh"|y_.ey+Wk.e?Y?thZjd,?hZ+@HhZ"ty"""@GeZ@+c"ten eleven twelve"d+R"teen"+c"thir four"d>H5eZ?hZ+@GhZ" hundred"""c.[03_b]1"thousand"c_jQT3"zero
```

Input is an integer in range [0-999,999]. Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%3Arjdb6%22++%2B%22dAm%2Bcd%3B%22nine%22%2C%22+one+two+three+four+five+six+seven+eight%22%22++twen+thir+for+fif+six+seven+eigh%22%7Cy_.ey%2BWk.e%3FY%3FthZjd%2C%3FhZ%2B%40HhZ%22ty%22%22%22%40GeZ%40%2Bc%22ten+eleven+twelve%22d%2BR%22teen%22%2Bc%22thir+four%22d%3EH5eZ%3FhZ%2B%40GhZ%22+hundred%22%22%22c.%5B03_b%5D1%22thousand%22c_jQT3%22zero&input=90210&debug=0). Explanation pending.

Previous version, very similar operation, but doesn't support 0:

```
L:rjdb6"  +"dJc" one two three four five six seven eight nine"dKc"  twen thir for fif six seven eigh nine"dy_.ey+Wk.e?Y?thZjd,?hZ+@KhZ"ty"""@JeZ@+c"ten eleven twelve"d+R"teen"+c"thir four"d>K5eZ?hZ+@JhZ" hundred"""c.[03_b]1"thousand"c_jQT3
```

Explanation of previous version:

```
Implicit: Q=eval(input()), d=" "

Step 1: output formatting helper function
L:rjdb6"  +"d   
L               Define a function, y(b):
   jdb          Join b on spaces
  r   6         Strip whitespace from beginning and end
 :              In the above, replace...
       "  +"    ... strings of more than one space...
            d   ... with a single space

Step 2: Define number lookup lists
Jc"..."dKc"..."d   
  "..."            Lookup string
 c     d           Split the above on spaces
J                  Store in J - this is list of unit names
        Kc"..."d   As above, but storing in K - this is list of tens names, without "ty"

Step 3: Bringing it all together
y_.ey+Wk.e?Y?thZjd,?hZ+@KhZ"ty"""@JeZ@+c"ten eleven twelve"d+R"teen"+c"thir four"d>K5eZ?hZ+@JhZ" hundred"""c.[03_b]1"thousand"c_jQT3   
                                                                                                                                jQT    Get digits of Q
                                                                                                                               _       Reverse
                                                                                                                              c    3   Split into groups of 3
  .e                                                                                                                                   Map the above, element as b, index as k, using:
                                                                                                                _b                       Reverse the digits in the group
                                                                                                            .[03                         Pad the above on the left with 0 to length 3
                                                                                                           c      ]1                     Chop at index 1 - [1,2,3] => [[1],[2,3]]
        .e                                                                                                                               Map the above, element as Z, index as Y, using:
          ?Y                                                                                                                               If second element in the group (i.e. tens and units):
            ?thZ                                                                                                                             If (tens - 1) is non-zero (i.e. 0 or >=2):
                   ?hZ                                                                                                                         If tens is non-zero:
                       @KhZ                                                                                                                      Lookup in tens names
                      +    "ty"                                                                                                                  Append "ty"
                                                                                                                                               Else:
                               ""                                                                                                                Empty string
                  ,                                                                                                                            Create two-element list of the above with...
                                 @JeZ                                                                                                          ... lookup units name
                jd                                                                                                                             Join the above on a space - this covers [0-9] and [20-99]
                                                                                                                                             Else:
                                                                     c"thir four"d                                                             ["thir", "four"]
                                                                    +             >K5                                                          Append last 5 element of tens names ("fif" onwards)
                                                            +R"teen"                                                                           Append "teen" to each string in the above
                                      +c"ten eleven twelve"d                                                                                   Prepend ["ten", "eleven", "twelve"]
                                     @                                               eZ                                                        Take string at index of units column - this covers [10-19]
                                                                                                                                           Else: (i.e. hundreds column)
                                                                                       ?hZ                                                   If hundreds column is non-zero:
                                                                                           @JhZ                                                Lookup units name
                                                                                          +    " hundred"                                      Append " hundred"
                                                                                                         ""                                  Else: empty string
                                                                                                                                         Result of map is two element list of [hundreds name, tens and units name]
      Wk                                                                                                                                 If k is nonzero (i.e. dealing with thousands group)...
     +                                                                                                              "thousand"           ... Append "thousand"
    y                                                                                                                                    Apply output formatting (join on spaces, strip, deduplicate spaces)
                                                                                                                                       Result of map is [units group string, thousands group string]
 _                                                                                                                                     Reverse group ordering to put thousands back in front
y                                                                                                                                      Apply output formatting again, implicit print
```