# Random literal number

Tags: code-golf

I took inspiration from a challenge I did some years ago in a programming competition.

Your goal is to write a **function** that generates a random **integer** number between **0** and **150** (included), and then prints it in actual words. For example, *139* would be printed as *onehundredthirtynine*.

**Rules:**

- You cannot use any external resource, nor any library that will perform the conversion.
- The shortest answer will win.

Good luck!

Comment: With or without spaces?

Comment: Without spaces, as you can see in the example! :)

Comment: ... Damn, I actually searched for it. Didn't use proper keywords :/

Comment: Don't worry, neither I found it easily. (I knew [another question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16217/cardinal-numbers-in-standard-american-english) which links to that one.)

Answer (score 0):

## Lua

```
print"four"
```

Highly optimized and golfed [xkcd's random number generator](http://xkcd.com/221/)

## An actual solution, 380

```
x=math.random(0,150)m=math.floor print(x==0 and"zero"or((x>99 and"onehundred"or"")..(({"ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen"})[x%100-9]or({[0]="",nil,"twenty","thirty","fourty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety"})[m(x/10)%10]..({[0]="","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"})[x%10])))
```

Comment: print"un" in French. How about just "un"?

Comment: PHP has barewords. 2 characters in PHP

Comment: still an invalid answer. This isn't [tag:code-trolling].

Comment: Besides, [Dilbert did such 6 years earlier.](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/)