# Number of characters in an integer's name

Tags: code-golf, string

The goal of this challenge is to show how many characters are in the name of a given integer. This is code golf, so the smallest code wins.

**RULES**

- The input will be between 0 and 100 (inclusive). If it is not the program won't return anything.
- The result has to be printed as `input : answer`
- Result for `100` is `hundred`

For example, if the input is `23` you have to count the numbers of letters `twenty-three` : here the answer is 12, and you should print `23 : 12`

Comment: I'm afraid this is too similar to [Converting integers to English words](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12766/converting-integers-to-english-words) to have any success.

Comment: @manatwork: I was looking for that question- thank you for finding it for me.

Comment: @manatwork meh, you found what i was searching this morning. Let's try to get some responses anyway..

Comment: Do we need to count the dash or not in numbers such as twenty-three? You said "how many letters" so I assume we should not, but  @Mohit Jain answer for instance does count the dash, and since there's only one example in your post I think you should clarify this.

Comment: Also what should we output for 100? "a hundred" and "one hundred" are both correct but are not the same number of letters. Some people in answers return the number of letters in "hundred" only.

Comment: @Fatalize yeah, by letters i meant characters .. i'll edit this, thanx !

Comment: Are you sure you want to require programs to give empty output on invalid input? Standard practice is to allow undefined behavior on invalid input.

Comment: @ThomasKwa yup, let's do some non-standard things :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Common Lisp - 72 bytes

```lisp
(lambda(x)(if(<= 0 x 100)(format t"~A : ~A~%"x(length(format()"~R"x)))))
```

#### Output from 0 to 20

```
0 : 4
1 : 3
2 : 3
3 : 5
4 : 4
5 : 4
6 : 3
7 : 5
8 : 5
9 : 4
10 : 3
11 : 6
12 : 6
13 : 8
14 : 8
15 : 7
16 : 7
17 : 9
18 : 8
19 : 8
20 : 6
```

Answer (score 4):

## C : 117 bytes

(From kind suggestion of @[edc65](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52280/number-of-characters-in-an-integers-name/52285#comment124580_52285) and @[ColeCameron](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52280/number-of-characters-in-an-integers-name/52285#comment124594_52285))

```c
f(a){char *d="0446554665366887798803665557667";printf("%d : %d",a,(a?a<20?d[a]-(a<10):d[a%10]+d[20+a/10]-48:52)-48);}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/tRmy3T)

## C++ : 159 bytes <del>178 bytes</del>

```c
int f(int a){char *d[3]={"0446554665","0366555766","3668877988"};printf("%d : %d",a,(a?a<20?a>9?d[2][a-10]:d[0][a]-1:a>99?55:d[0][a%10]+d[1][a/10]-48:52)-48);}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/IeeoMg)

## Explanation

Explanation from previous code, with all suggestions from comments incorporated.

```c
int f(int a) {  // Return int to save a byte, a is the argument

    int d[3][10]={
             {0,4,4,6,5,5,4,6,6,5},  // Length of "", "-one", "-two", "-three" etc.
             {0,3,6,6,5,5,5,7,6,6},  // Length of "", "ten", "twenty", etc.
             {3,6,6,8,8,7,7,9,8,8}   // Length of "ten", "eleven", etc.
           };
    printf ("%d : %d", a,
               a 
                 // If a is not zero
                 ? a < 20
                     // If a is less than 20
                     ? a > 9
                         // a is in range 10-19
                         ? d[2][a-10]
                         // a is in range 0-9
                         : d[0][a]-1  // Subtract one as '-' is not required
                     // If a is >= 20
                     : a > 99
                         // If a is 100
                         ? 7  // Length of hundred
                         // a is between 20-99
                         : d[0][a%10] + d[1][a/10]  // unit digit length + tens digit length
                 // If a is zero
                 : 4
            );
}
```

Comment: I really like the explanation on this one.. If you save the length oh 0 in your tab of int, i think you can save on or two bytes :  int d[3][10]={{5,4,4,6,5,5,4,6,6,5},...} for -zero, you delete the first test and it might be ok with the d[0][a]-1 (when a is in range 0-9). Not tested.

Comment: @Therandomguy I will try your suggestion and let the code run through my tester. Thanks.

Comment: 138: http://ideone.com/B4xSXr `f(a){int d[]={0,4,4,6,5,5,4,6,6,5,3,6,6,8,8,7,7,9,8,8,0,3,6,6,5,5,5,7,6,6,7};printf("%d : %d",a,a?a<20?d[a]-(a<10):d[a%10]+d[20+a/10]:4);}`

Comment: I'm a noob with ideone, so i can't tell how many bytes i save on your code. But as i said you can do without excluding the 0 : `f(a){int d[]={5,4,4,6,5,5,4,6,6,5,3,6,6,8,8,7,7,9,8,8,0,3,6,6,5,5,5,7,6,6,7};printf("%d : %d",a,a<20?d[a]-(a<10):d[a%10]+d[20+a/10]);}` (This solution save 4 characters)

Comment: `f(a){char d[]="0446554665366887798803665557667";printf("%d : %d",a,a?a<20?d[a]-48-(a<10):d[a%10]-48+d[20+a/10]-48:4);}`

Comment: I noticed i could combine some of the arithmetic expressions to save another 3 bytes...just after the edit window closed :(

Comment: wurf. let's hope @Mohit Jain will edit his answer and will notice you

Comment: @ColeCameron the string trick is really clever (-48 is the clever part)

Comment: @CleCameron Therandomguy Thanks, incorporated.

Comment: @edc65 Thanks for the professional code :) I will update my answer with this also, hope you won't mind.

Answer (score 0):

## Prolog, <s>261</s> 211 bytes

```
u(X,Y):-nth0(X,[4,3,3,5,4,4,3,5,5,4,3,6,6,8,8,7,7,9,8,8],Y).
a(X):-X>=0,X<101,(X=100,Y=7;X<20,u(X,Y);A is X//10-2,nth0(A,[6,6,5,5,5,7,6,6],B),C is X-X//10*10,(C=0,D=0;u(C,D)),Y is B+D+1),writef('%t : %t',[X,Y]).
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 172 bytes

```python
l='33544355436688779980'
a='776668778'
n=int(raw_input())
if n==0:
 print n,':',4
elif n<20:
 print n,':',l[n-1]
elif n<100:
 print n,':',int(a[n/10-2])+int(l[n-n/10*10-1])
```

Stores all the units number name lengths in a string, from 1 to 19. Combines them with 10s number name lengths if the number >=20.

`0` is an exception. `100` is taken to be `hundred`.

Comment: May `n==0` be `n<1`? In any case, you could save characters by using a ternary or array indexing instead of the if:elif:elif.

Comment: @ThomasKwa will look into the second suggestion. if it is a negative number it would return something without the ==1

Comment: @ThomasKwa I thought that, but then he said *If it is not the program won't return anything.*

Comment: This doesn't follow the spec at all.. All of them need to be the same format (i.e. `0` should print `0 : 4`, not just `4`, and `17` should print `17 : 9`, not just `9`). It's shorter to just put `':'` instead of `chr(58)`, `n-int(n/10)*10-1` can be shortened to `n%10-1`, and since this is Python 2, you can do `n/10-2` instead of `int(n/10)-2`.

Answer (score 0):

**PHP**
613 Characters

As a bonus, I don't use a dictionary of integer character lengths.

```
<?php $i=10;$b[0]='zero';$b[1]='one';$b[2]='two';$b[3]='three';$b[4]='four';$b[5]='five';$b[6]='six';$b[7]='seven';$b[8]='eight';$b[9]='nine';$t='teen';$c[0]='ten';$c[1]='eleven';$c[2]='tweleve';$c[3]='thir'.$t;$c[4]=$b[4].$t;$c[5]='fif'.$t;$c[6]=$b[6].$t;$c[7]=$b[7].$t;$c[8]=$b[8].$t;$c[9]=$b[9].$t;$d[2]='twenty';$d[3]='thirty';$d[4]='fourty';$d[5]='fifty';$d[6]='sixty';$d[7]='seventy';$d[8]='eighty';$d[9]='ninety';$z='onehundred';$j=str_split($i);if(strlen($i)===1){$a=$b[$i];}elseif(strlen($i===3)){$a=$z;}elseif(substr($i,0,1)==='1'){$a=$c[$j[1]];}else{$a=$d[$j[0]].' '.$b[$j[1]];}echo$i.' : '.strlen($a);
```

**Long hand**

```
<?php
// Input
$i=10;
// 0-9
$b[0]='zero';
$b[1]='one';
$b[2]='two';
$b[3]='three';
$b[4]='four';
$b[5]='five';
$b[6]='six';
$b[7]='seven';
$b[8]='eight';
$b[9]='nine';
// 10-19 (Very tricky)
$t='teen';
$c[0]='ten';
$c[1]='eleven';
$c[2]='tweleve';
$c[3]='thir'.$t;
$c[4]=$b[4].$t;
$c[5]='fif'.$t;
$c[6]=$b[6].$t;
$c[7]=$b[7].$t;
$c[8]=$b[8].$t;
$c[9]=$b[9].$t;
// Left digit of 20-99
$d[2]='twenty';
$d[3]='thirty';
$d[4]='fourty';
$d[5]='fifty';
$d[6]='sixty';
$d[7]='seventy';
$d[8]='eighty';
$d[9]='ninety';
// 100
$z='one hundred';
// Split input
$j=str_split($i);
// 1 digit inputs
if (strlen($i)===1){$a=$b[$i];}
// 3 digit input
else if (strlen($i===3)){$a=$z;}
// 10-19
else if (substr($i, 0, 1)==='1'){$a=$c[$j[1]];}
// 20-99
else{$a=$d[$j[0]].' '.$b[$j[1]];}
// result
echo $i.' : '.strlen($a);
```

Comment: You can save a huge amount of bytes if you give the length of the number in your tabs instead of writing it and counting the amount of characters. For example instead of $c[1]='eleven'; you can write $c[1]=6;

Comment: As I said in the post, I wanted to accomplish it without a dictionary.

Comment: Oh ok, my bad. I need to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 158 Bytes

Just a little bit of hex :)

```python
n=input()
print(`n`+' : '+`int('433544355436688779886aacbbaccb6aacbbaccb599baa9bba599baa9bba599baa9bba7bbdccbddc6aacbbaccb6aacbbaccb7'[n%101],16)`)*(-1<n<101)
```

Comment: @Sp3000 That would be correct, I believe I've fixed it now.

Comment: simple question : i just saw this 0<n<101 ... when n=0, what this code do ? (normally it should show 0 : 4)

Comment: @Therandomguy good catch, I updated it :)

Comment: @Therandomguy I'm not sure if it's possible, but you should un-accept my answer, coredump's is shorter. And in the future, most people prefer when you allow undefined behavior when something is not within the range of inputs.

Comment: .. Yup, you're right. Time for me to sleep.