# Number letter counts

Tags: code-golf, number

If the numbers 1 to 5 are written out in words: one, two, three, four, five, then there are 3 + 3 + 5 + 4 + 4 = 19 letters used in total.

Output how many letters would be used if all the numbers from 1 to 1000 (one thousand) inclusive were written out in words.

*NOTE: Do not count spaces or hyphens. For example, 342 (three hundred and forty-two) contains 23 letters and 115 (one hundred and fifteen) contains 20 letters. The use of "and" when writing out numbers is in compliance with British usage.*

You must actually calculate it - just printing the predetermined result is not allowed.

Output with [any acceptable method.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)

Comment: Probable duplicate of [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12766/converting-integers-to-english-words)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! To prevent hardcoding, I'd strongly recommend to either 1) take a number \$1\le N \le 1000\$ as input and ask the number of letters used to write \$1\$ to \$N\$ or 2) take 2 numbers \$A\$ and \$B\$ as input and ask the number of letters used to write \$A\$ to \$B\$.

Comment: This would be better as "output how many letters are used if the numbers 1 through n were written out" to avoid any question of whether something prints a predetermined result. But I think that's a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, it does seem similar enough to be a duplicate, thanks.

Comment: It turns out that this is a slightly edited copy of [problem 17](https://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=017) from Project Euler. Posting such problems here is [strongly discouraged](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1082/58563), so it should probably be closed and/or deleted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this challenge was taken from another site without any reference or authorization.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 38 bytes

```
StringLength@StringJoin@IntegerName[Range[1000]]
```

@Doorknob has a leaner implementation:

```
Tr@StringLength@IntegerName@Range@1000
```

(* 20961 *)

---

*Explanation*

```
IntegerName[Range[10]]
```

(* {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"} *)

```
StringJoin@IntegerName[Range[10]]
```

(* "onetwothreefourfivesixseveneightnineten" *)

```
StringLength@StringJoin@IntegerName[Range[10]]
```

(* 39 *)

Comment: Since `StringLength` threads over lists (and you can use prefix notation for all of these functions), this can be shortened to `Tr@StringLength@IntegerName@Range@1000` to save 10 bytes.

Comment: @Doorknob:  Oooh... yes.  Nice.  Thanks.

Comment: The expected result is [21124](https://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-17-letters-in-the-numbers-1-1000/). The gap is prime (21124 - 20961 = 163), so it's not \$N\$ times the same difference. I wonder where it comes from.

Comment: When I delete white spaces I get 19169.

Comment: Are you also deleting hyphens? And are the numbers formatted the UK way? (_three hundred **and** forty-two_)?

Comment: Not deleting hyphens.  Obviously, I'm using Wolfram's *Mathematica* conventions for number words.

Comment: FWIW, it seems like _IntegerName_ has _language_ and _country_ options. So, that might be fixable at a (rather) reasonable cost.

Comment: I'm not sure that converting from *American English* to *British English* is "fixing" the solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), <s>104</s> <s>98</s> <s>85</s> <s>76</s> <s>75</s> 74 bytes

```lisp
(princ(loop for i to 999 sum(count-if'both-case-p(format nil"~R"(1+ i)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fco7DoAgDADQqzQs1hgGR67hDbCR2ARow2f16lXf/ChzVzPUxpUwiygkacAwBEII0GdBklmH57ScMm5PsV9e8VslDqic3XM43Dfg9Wf2Ag)